# Browsers cannot find Java installed in another drive

Tags: java, firefox, browser, plugins, installation

due to space reasons, I have changed the directory (E: instead of C:) in which I installed Java JRE. However, my browsers do not seem to be able to find the Java plugin when I do this. I have tried this with multiple browers (Firefox, Opera) so I do not think it is browser specific.

Is there any other setting I need to change? I have kept the folder names the same. And I am using Windows 10.

I have checked "Configure Java" and Java is enabled. Clicking on "Update Java" in the Java Control Panel also shows me that it is the latest version.

How can I get Java to work in my browsers?

Comment: go to this url to verify that java is correctely installed for your browser https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

Comment: No, this java.com link is showing me it is not installed. But I have installed it.

Comment: Did you install java 32 bits or 64 bits in E:?

Comment: java 7+ firefox addon works only in firefox 64 bits. Verify that you have firefox 64 bits installed.

Comment: I have 64 bit and Java is 64 bit too. And it is also not firefox specific as I mentioned, it applies to my Opera browser too.